# Python from java

Tags: java, python, oracle

I have a Python script that connects to Oracle db and exports to an excel file. In Python the script works, but when I try to run it from java I get the following error:

```
import cx_Oracle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'.
```

I have have the oracle client and have set ORACLE_HOME.

My code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"python3", "path_to_py_file"});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How is it you're trying to run the Python script from Java?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please provide more information on the environment, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"python3", "path_to_py_file"}); If I do another think in the file works fine. The issue is when try to import the cx_Oracle lib.

Comment: When adding new information, please add it to the question using [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60536281/edit).

Comment: I see an answer has been marked as correct, so this is just a side comment.  If you have Oracle Instant Client, then you shouldn't set ORACLE_HOME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` requires the full path to the python:

```
ProcessBuilder(<path_to_python>, <absolute_file_path_to_python_script>);
```